# mongodb, replicates and error: { "$err" : "not master and slaveOk=false", "code" : 13435 }

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I tried mongo replica sets for the first time.

I am using ubuntu on ec2 and I booted up three instances.
I used the private IP address of each of the instances.  I picked on as the primary and below is the code.

```
mongo --host Private IP Address
rs.initiate()
rs.add(“Private IP Address”)
rs.addArb(“Private IP Address”)
```

All at this point is fine.  When I go to the http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:28017/_replSet site I see that I have a primary, seconday, and arbitor.

Ok, now for a test.

On the primary create a database in this is the code:

```
use tt
db.tt.save( { a : 123 } )
```

on the secondary, I then do this and get the below error:

```
db.tt.find()
error: { "$err" : "not master and slaveOk=false", "code" : 13435 }
```

I am very new to mongodb and replicates but I thought that if I do something in one, it goes to the other.  So, if I add a record in one, what do I have to do to replicate across machines?

Comment: figured out that I have to use rs.slaveOk();  That leaves me to another question.  I have to do this do this for every query?  What if I am on the master node?

Answer (score 319):

You have to set "secondary okay" mode to let the mongo shell know that you're allowing reads from a secondary. This is to protect you and your applications from performing eventually consistent reads by accident. You can do this in the shell with:

```
rs.secondaryOk()
```

After that you can query normally from secondaries.

A note about "eventual consistency": under normal circumstances, replica set secondaries have all the same data as primaries within a second or less. Under very high load, data that you've written to the primary may take a while to replicate to the secondaries. This is known as "replica lag", and reading from a lagging secondary is known as an "eventually consistent" read, because, while the newly written data will show up at some point (barring network failures, etc), it may not be immediately available.

**Edit:** You only need to set `secondaryOk` when querying from secondaries, and only once per session.

Comment: Always check the manual before you go executing commands you don't understand on your DBs. There could be consequences to the command that the answer doesn't explain. Does this command change the way read ope rations are distributed for all connections to the replica set? Better find out. This command appears as far back as v2.2 https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.2/reference/method/rs.slaveOk/ You can (and should) always replace the "/manual/" portion of a docs.mongodb.com URL to your specific version to make sure you are getting relevant info.

Comment: `slaveOk()` is deprecated and may be removed in the next major release. Please use `secondaryOk()` instead.

Answer (score 50):

To avoid typing `rs.slaveOk()` every time, do this:

Create a file named `replStart.js`, containing one line: `rs.slaveOk()`

Then include `--shell replStart.js` when you launch the Mongo shell.  Of course, if you're connecting locally to a single instance, this doesn't save any typing.

Comment: A better way to save on typing would be to add `rs.slaveOk()` to your [`~/.mongorc.js`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo/#mongo-mongorc-file) file, which will be automatically executed when starting the mongo shell.

Comment: I find it useful to put the default configuration in `~/.mongorc.js` and custom configurations in `replStart.js` or `adminStart.js` or whatever.

Answer (score 43):

in mongodb2.0

you should type

```
rs.slaveOk()
```

in secondary mongod node

Answer (score 13):

**THIS IS JUST A NOTE FOR ANYONE DEALING WITH THIS PROBLEM USING THE RUBY DRIVER**

*I had this same problem when using the Ruby Gem.*

To set slaveOk in Ruby, you just pass it as an argument when you create the client like this:

```
mongo_client = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017, { slave_ok: true })
```

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Tutorial#making-a-connection

```
mongo_client = MongoClient.new # (optional host/port args)
```

Notice that 'args' is the third optional argument.

Answer (score 8):

I got here searching for the same error, but from [Node.js native driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/). The answer for me was combination of answers by [campeterson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921846/336753) and [Prabhat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57733698/336753).

The issue is that `readPreference` setting defaults to `primary`, which then somehow leads to the confusing `slaveOk` error. My problem is that I just wan to read from my replica set from any node. I don't even connect to it as to replicaset. I just connect to any node to read from it.

Setting `readPreference` to `primaryPreferred` (or better to the `ReadPreference.PRIMARY_PREFERRED` constant) solved it for me. Just pass it as an option to `MongoClient.connect()` or to `client.db()` or to any `find()`, `aggregate()` or other function.

- https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/read-preference/#primaryPreferred
- http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html (search *readPreference*)

```js
const { MongoClient, ReadPreference } = require('mongodb');
const client = await MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_CONNECTIONSTRING, { readPreference: ReadPreference.PRIMARY_PREFERRED });
```

Answer (score 7):

**WARNING**: `slaveOk()` is deprecated and may be removed in the next major release. Please use `secondaryOk()` (in the mongo shell) instead.

Answer (score 4):

slaveOk does not work anymore. One needs to use readPreference https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/read-preference/#primaryPreferred

e.g.

```
const client = new MongoClient(mongoURL + "?readPreference=primaryPreferred", { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

I am just adding this answer for an awkward situation from DB provider.

what happened in our case is the primary and secondary db shifted reversely (primary to secondary and vice versa) and we are getting the same error.

so please check in the configuration settings for database status which may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding readPreference as PRIMARY

```
const { MongoClient, ReadPreference } = require('mongodb');
const client = new MongoClient(url, { readPreference: ReadPreference.PRIMARY_PREFERRED});
client.connect();
```