# Issue with installation of rocketchat on RHEL 7.2

Tags: rocket.chat

I am trying to install Rocket Chat server on RHEL 7.2 using the CentOS procedure listed at:
https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/centos

The installation itself ran fine with no noticeable errors. However, when I try to start the service, I get the error.

```
[cinstall@xxxxxxxxxx ~]$ sudo systemctl status rocketchat
â rocketchat.service - The Rocket.Chat server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rocketchat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-01-03 11:14:11 UTC; 24h ago
  Process: 16375 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /opt/Rocket.Chat/main.js (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 16375 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 03 11:14:11 ibmsitldct02 systemd[1]: Started The Rocket.Chat server.
Jan 03 11:14:11 ibmsitldct02 systemd[1]: Starting The Rocket.Chat server...
Jan 03 11:14:11 ibmsitldct02 systemd[1]: rocketchat.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 03 11:14:11 ibmsitldct02 systemd[1]: Unit rocketchat.service entered failed state.
Jan 03 11:14:11 ibmsitldct02 systemd[1]: rocketchat.service failed.
```

Additional information:

```
[cinstall@xxxxxxxxxx ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

node --version ==> v8.11.3
npm --version  ==> 5.6.0
n --version    ==> 2.1.12


[cinstall@xxxxxxxxxx ~]$ sudo systemctl status mongod
â mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-12-19 12:42:08 UTC; 2 weeks 1 days ago
 Main PID: 17501 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           ââ17501 /usr/bin/mongod --quiet -f /etc/mongod.conf run

Dec 19 12:42:08 ibmsitldct02 systemd[1]: Starting High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database...
Dec 19 12:42:08 ibmsitldct02 mongod[17499]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Dec 19 12:42:08 ibmsitldct02 mongod[17499]: forked process: 17501
Dec 19 12:42:08 ibmsitldct02 systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
```

Comment: Hey and welcome on Stackoverflow. I suggest you to start RocketChat again and look for more logs in `/var/log/messages`. There should be more logs which can help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Rohlik, thanks for your suggestion. The var logs have slightly more details:

Comment: Jan  7 16:39:20 xxxxxxxxx systemd: Started The Rocket.Chat server.
Jan  7 16:39:20 xxxxxxxxx systemd: Starting The Rocket.Chat server...
Jan  7 16:39:20 xxxxxxxxx rocketchat: module.js:681
Jan  7 16:39:20 xxxxxxxxx rocketchat: return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
Jan  7 16:39:20 xxxxxxxxx rocketchat: ^
Jan  7 16:39:20 xxxxxxxxx rocketchat: Error: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-57/fibers.node)

Comment: $ ls -lrt /lib64/libstdc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 830776 Mar  5  2015 /lib64/libstdc++.so.5.0.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 991616 Oct 30 06:39 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 Dec 19 12:26 /lib64/libstdc++.so.5 -> libstdc++.so.5.0.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 Jan  2 14:12 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19

Comment: It is look like a already reported bug, look for workaround here - https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/9167

Comment: Thank you Rohlik! The link resolved the library issue. I have rebuild fibers.node. Now I am stuck with next error, this time with meteor-mongodb.                                        rocketchat: MongoError: not master and slaveOk=false
rocketchat: at queryCallback (/opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:233:23)

Comment: rocketchat: at /opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:532:18
rocketchat: at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
rocketchat: at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Comment: Your problem should be fixed by this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34133235/5102940