# How to specify the path to config file in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, powershell

In config file I have:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    logAppend: true
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db
    journal:
        enabled: true
replication:
   replSetName: "rs0"
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
security:
     authorization: enabled
```

[image]

I'm trying to connect using `mongod` process like in [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#use-the-configuration-file):

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin> mongod --auth --dbpath /data/db --config C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg
```

And getting:

> Error reading config file: No such file or directory
>   try 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe --help' for more information

[image]

Then trying with quotes

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin> mongod --auth --dbpath /data/db --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg"
```

and getting:

> 2018-07-02T02:49:21.272+0300 I CONTROL  [main] log file "c:\data\log\mongod.log" exists; moved to "c:\data\log\mongod.log.2018-07-01T23-49-21".

[image]
Starting `mongo`, then `show dbs` and see: [image]

If I'm writting this snippet (without config), everything is fine:

```
mongod --auth --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip 127.0.0.1
```

[image]
With `mongo`: 
[image]
What I'm doing wrong? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you think something is still wrong after you added quotes around the path? The message is just telling you that `mongod` rotated the log file. And since your config does specify a log file I'd expect all the output you'd otherwise see on the console to go to that log.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers because then I can't see my databases via `mongo` process

using `mongo --port 27017 -u "myuser" -p "mypassword" --authenticationDatabase "admin"`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers `show dbs `->
`2018-07-02T14:34:47.242+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listDatabases failed:{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false",
        "code" : 13435,
        "codeName" : "NotMasterNoSlaveOk"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:65:1
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:849:19
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:739:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1`.

`show collections` same error

Comment: Your config file specifies a [replication set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8990158/1630171), your daemon start from the commandline does not.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thank you a lot, solve it by using `rs.slaveOk()`, but can I add `rs.slaveOk()` directly to my config file instead of permanently writing this before `show dbs` and `show collections`?

Comment: I think you need to invoke it when starting the Mongo shell (see the answer provided by Ed Harris). I don't have that much experience with MongoDB, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Thanks to recomendation by Ansgar, I solved it.

1. To avoid the error like: `not master and slaveOk = false` need always using the command: [`rs.slaveOk()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8990428/8370915).
2. To avoid typing `rs.slaveOk()` every time need to add `rs.slaveOk()` in `.mongorc.js` file [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15623540/8370915) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#files)
3. More detail [information](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165444/153538).